# Old wiring trying to change a switch outlet to half hot outlet

Tags: wiring, switch, receptacle, old-work

In setting up my work from home office in my 1950's triplex I am trying to change an outlet from a switch to half hot.

I snapped the tab on the side but when I was working with the wires realized I need more guidance. I have two white wires attached on the silver side, and a black wire on the brass side, plus three black wires not attached and just bunched together in the box behind the outlet with some electrical tape on the end. Also no ground wire.

With the tab snapped I can get the bottom one to work with the switch, the top is now dead.

Please help!

[image: Outlet 1]

[image: Side view]

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pkoef.png): [image: Silver side]

Comment: Pull the outlet out of the box, and then do whatever you need to in order to light the backside of the box area, snap a photo, and [edit] it into your question.   Do your best; if the lighting isn't perfect someone will brighten it up in Photoshop.  Keep in mind if you change browsers or devices to do this, it'll really help to register your account ([here](https://diy.stackexchange.com/users/mylogins/116473) and tie to Google, Facebook or email/password).  That way you'll be able to log in on your other device and it'll let you edit this question from there.

Comment: Can you post photos looking into the back of the box please?